# Orchard CMS Internet shop

Tags: ecommerce, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Does anyone know where to find tutorial how to make an Internet shop by using Orchard CMS?

I'm new at web programming, but I have experience with .Net technologies.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of e-commerce modules in [Orchard Gallery](http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/ByCategory/Modules/Commerce) atm.
I'd advise you to watch Drew Robbins build a [Flower Store](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix/mix11/key01) at MIX11. It's short, but may be a great help!

HTH

Answer (score 1):

there is great document http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/ but at first i suggest you change your mind to use this cms... there is great cms only for shop in all languages ;)

Comment: @user6857 - Could you clarify what you mean in your answer about changing your mind?